# How load a single random post on Tumblr + advice

Tags: tumblr

I'm redesigning my website to function as a new media gallery. I like Tumblr because of it's social connectedness, but I'm concerned there might be technical limitations.

Things I'd like to do.

- Display only one post at a time - load this randomly
- Include a 'random' button which reloads the page to display another random post
- Lightweight animated SWF background (possibly load randomly)
- Loop a video
- Display 'likes' somewhere on the page

I've checked out flavors.me and while it's well done, it's not flexible enough yet. Is there a better CMS solution or any other emerging solution I don't know about? I will still probably end up using Tumblr for blog.mydomain.com

If I need to get help with the development, is Freelancer.com a suitable place to hire a developer for Tumblr? I've hired people for Wordpress before, but I don't know much about the Tumblr situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Random will work for Random  - /random is built into tumblr

Comment: Well, it doesn't really do random - it only loads a few dozen different pages, and keeps cycling through them. (I've got a Tumblr with thousands of posts, but /random keeps only showing the same 30-40.)

Answer (score 1):

Most of these things are totally possible with tumblr.

> - Display only one post at a time

You can tell tumblr to only show a single post per page

1. Go to http://tumblr.com/customize/blog-name (replace blog-name with your blog's name)
2. In the Customize panel scroll down to the bottom and click on 'advanced options'
3. There is a 'posts per page' dropdown, choose to show only a single post.

> - load this randomly Include a 'random' button which reloads the page to display another random post

Tumblr comes with a random post functionality, you can create a link/button that point to http://blog-name.tumblr.com/random and clicking it will take the user to a random post.

If you want to dynamically and automatically show random posts on the main page, you may need to use some javascript magic. (I imagine this getting very hacky)

Basically have 15 posts on the front page, and have them all set to "display:none". Then have javascript change which post is displayed on a timer. This would break for people with javascript turned off, so you would need to have a different css for fallback. (I have personally seen a ton of tumblr themes that totally break when javascript is turned off. ie: http://theme-matte.tumblr.com/ looks fantastic, but doesn't load anything if javascript is turned off.

It would be easier to show random posts if you used self hosted Wordpress, as you would have access to the database and could just make calls to that to pull posts.

> - Lightweight animated SWF background (possibly load randomly) Loop a video

Tumblr gives you access to the html and css for themes, so this wouldn't be hard to do, there is a nice tutorial here: http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_flashbackground.html

> - Display 'likes' somewhere on the page

You can show likes and reblogs and all sorts of meta data in a sidebar or in post footer. Tumblr has documentation on this here:

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#likes

> Is there a better CMS solution or any other emerging solution I don't know about?

You could check out koken, which is a CMS solution for images that is very robust and with pretty default themes: http://koken.me/

The Secretary is also a portfolio CMS: http://www.thesecretary.org/

And Stacey: http://www.staceyapp.com/ Stacey is very basic, but it's also very easy to theme.

> is Freelancer.com a suitable place to hire a developer for Tumblr?

Freelancer and Odesk would be fine for hiring a web developer to do a custom theme. I work on those sites myself and there are plenty of tumblr developers on there.

PS: I am available to hire for theme development if you decide to go the tumblr route. The most current theme I'm developing for tumblr: http://passepartout-theme.tumblr.com/ (still under construction) If you are interested you can contact me at hello {@} doloresportalatin.info and if not, I hope this helped you out a bit. :)